# How To Call Rails Backend From Grpc Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, grpc

Hey guys I have a GRPC server I have set up locally in my rails app that I can successfully call and retrieve a message back from. My question is how do I now use my grpc server to call something in my rails app?

For instance my grpc server is in ./grpc/fnma_server.rb and I want to call a method in a class located at: ./lib/example_app/api_class.rb. This call with then make a call to a seperate api and return a boolean, I want to just take this boolean and then return it to the original caller to the GRPC server. What is the best way to do this?

It is tough as well because my api_class is altering tables in my DB for the rails app using active record so I can not just include the file into the grpc server.

Big Picture of what I want to do:

App A = My Rails App, App B = Rails App Calling My App

App B sends App A a request using GRPC, App A (with the GRPC Server) then takes this data, formats it, and sends it to an API that returns a boolean value. App A then (using GRPC) sends a response back to App A with the boolean return value for each of the calls.

Comment: Best way to call Rails from an external service is to just run a REST API on the Rails server, and then use HTTP to access it. Of course if you want you can modify the Rails DB through ActiveRecord, but then you create a code coupling and dependency on your Rails code from your external server.

Comment: Is there still a benefit to using GRPC at that point? Since the GRPC server has to wait fot the slower rest call to the Rails Backend before spitting back its proto buff response to the original caller?

Comment: Would the best solution be to make a rails controller I can call from the GRPC server that just calls my ruby code and returns an answer? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Why involve Rails at all? If you want efficiency why not build everything into the GPRC server? If you have lib code then just require it, but be aware that if your lib code has Rails dependencies, you will pull everything with it.

Comment: I have logic on a rails server that calls and api, gets a boolean response, and stores that response in a local DB using active record. I could move the API call into the grpc server easily but then how should I go about storing that into my database that is tied to a rails app?

Big picture as well I want to have other rails applications call my application using grpc and then use logic in my rails app to return a response, what is the best way to do that in general? For instance another rails app calls my app to get back a boolean response and for my app to store that data, with GRPC

Comment: If your Rails app has some magic code that does something, then put this magic code into module X. This module X can then be included in both GPRC and Rails. This decouples Rails from GPRC and GPRC from Rails. The other options is call Rails with HTTP, or use ActiveRecord from GPRC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Casper, if I move my code to a module wouldn't I still have to include dependencies into my GRPC server? For instance I can move the logic to a module and then include that in GRPC, but if say I make HTTP calls and write to my DB in the module using active record I would need to: "require 'net/http'" and require 'active_record' in grpc still correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. This is why you will get the cleanest API by calling HTTP on Rails, but as you say, you lose the speed. However what difference does it make, if your module X then still uses HTTP itself? The fastest code will be using ActiveRecord, but if that is not possible, then module X (with HTTP or other requirements) is your other solution.

Comment: Makes sense thanks a ton Casper appreciate it

Comment: @Casper What is the best way to call my rails app from the GRPC server? How do I make the REST request to my existing code in a controller I have made

Comment: You can use any HTTP gem, or even native net/http. Some simple gems could be HTTParty (should be relatively lightweight), rest-clent is another more REST focused. More similar gems here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients

Comment: @Casper Gotcha, I am able to set up a http call, but how do I expose say one of my function in my current ruby app in say /lib/random_file.rb to be called?